# React fetch polyfill on mobile devices not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, fetch, polyfills

Trying to get fetch to work on ios/android (chrome & safari).
I currently have this in my webpack (using webpack 4):

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
   Promise: 'imports-loader?this=>global!exports-loader?global.Promise!es6-promise',
   fetch: 'imports-loader?this=>global!exports-loader?global.fetch!whatwg-fetch'
}),
```

With this code it works for IE desktop, but on my android it gives the following error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
```

The fetch code:

```
fetch('http://localhost:8092/api/shops/search?searchString=spicy')
    .then(function(response) {
        if (response.status >= 400) {
            throw new Error("Bad response from server");
        }
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(function(stories) {
        console.log('hej', stories);
    });
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your `http://localhost:8092` is correctly resolved while on your desktop (assume to `127.0.0.1`), but for your mobile device - `localhost` is this particular device, not your desktop. So I guess you should try to use ip address which can be accessible through all of your network (instead of just `localhost`), assuming your mobile device is connected to the same one.